# Attempting to create Vertex AI Managed Notebook fails with error: Failed to insert a GCE VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I’m trying to create a number of vertex AI managed notebooks in GCP (note, not user managed notebooks, but managed notebooks). Each one fails with the same error:

```
2023-07-10T02:36:05.3813609Z e[31m│e[0m e[0me[1me[31mError: e[0me[0me[1mError waiting to create Runtime: Error waiting for Creating Runtime: Error code 3, message: operation “projects//locations/australia-southeast1/operations/create-d73db12f-8b7e-48eb-af84-7aadae580bd1” completed with error: %!w(*status.Status=&{{{}   } 3 Http(400) Bad Request; [ExecuteComputeApi] failed.; [VM][:vm-d73db12f-8b7e-48eb-af84-7aadae580bd1] ; Failed to insert a GCE VM   131})e[0m

2023-07-10T02:36:05.3814103Z e[31m│e[0m e[0m

2023-07-10T02:36:05.3814380Z e[31m│e[0m e[0me[0m with module.user2notebook.google_notebooks_runtime.runtime,

2023-07-10T02:36:05.3814746Z e[31m│e[0m e[0m on notebook_module/notebook_module.tf line 16, in resource “google_notebooks_runtime” “runtime”:

2023-07-10T02:36:05.3815095Z e[31m│e[0m e[0m 16: resource “google_notebooks_runtime” “runtime” e[4m{e[0me[0m

2023-07-10T02:36:05.3815319Z e[31m│e[0m e[0m
```

- I have ruled out permissions, as we have elevated the service account
  being used to manage the deployment all the way up to OWNER of the
  project.
- All the required APIs are running in the GCP project, as we can
  manually create a managed notebook via the console UI in Vertex AI
  without issue (same settings).
- I have ruled out issues with the network and subnet being shared with
  this project from the shared VPC project (again, because the manual
  creation works fine).

Google Support have said it’s a Terraform issue, so here I am unfortunately.

Here is the module I created to stand up each notebook:

```
variable “user_name” {
description = “Name of the user”
type = string
}

variable “user_email” {
description = “Email of the user”
type = string
}

variable “machine_type” {
description = “Machine type for the notebook instance”
type = string
}

resource “google_notebooks_runtime” “runtime” {
name = “${lower(replace(replace(var.user_email, “@”, “-”), “.”, “-”))}-notebook-instance”
location = “australia-southeast1”
access_config {
access_type = “SINGLE_USER”
runtime_owner = var.user_email
}
virtual_machine {
virtual_machine_config {
machine_type = var.machine_type
internal_ip_only = true
network = var.NETWORK
subnet = var.SUBNET
data_disk {
initialize_params {
disk_size_gb = “100”
disk_type = “PD_STANDARD”
}
}

  metadata = {
    app    = "inventory-mlops"
    bu     = var.BU
    owner  = var.OWNER
    costcentre = var.COSTCENTRE
    email  = var.user_email
  }
  labels = {
    app    = "inventory-mlops"
    bu     = var.BU
    owner  = var.OWNER
    costcentre = var.COSTCENTRE
    email  = var.user_email
  }
}
}
timeouts {
create = “30m”
delete = “30m”
}
}
```

And calling it from main.tf

```
module "user21notebook" {
  source = "./notebook_module"
  
  user_name = "James Matson"
  user_email = "james.matson@api.net.au"
  machine_type = "n1-standard-1"
}
```

It seems to me to be set up correctly according to this reference (the only reliable one I can find online for Vertex AI managed notebooks)

https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-docs-samples/blob/main/vertex_ai/managed_notebooks_runtime/main.tf

Comment: Based entirely on the error message this would appear to be an issue in the Google provider.

Comment: This [document](https://nakamasato.medium.com/set-up-vertex-ai-workbench-with-access-to-bigquery-and-gcs-using-terraform-3844e7cb65bb) is about setting up Vertex AI Workbench with access to BigQuery and GCS using Terraform. Does this document help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Believe it or not, this issue was resolved by removing the labels and metadata blocks entirely, as I was told - despite the documentation in Hashicorp listing them as valid blocks - they are not supported for managed notebooks. Removed, re-ran, deployed fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and encountered the same issue mentioned above at first. However, It seems that I was using the wrong values in the Lables field for lebel in my code and once I fixed it, it ran like a charm.

You can try something like

```
labels = {
  owner = "aman"
}
```

For everyone's convenience, here are some valid label value examples:

Alphanumeric Characters:
key1: value123
environment: production

Hyphens and Underscores:
app-version: v1-2-3
instance_name: my_instance

Lowercase Letters:
team: engineering
project: my_project

I hope these guidelines prove helpful.